# Knative Serving just returns default Apache Webpage

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, knative, knative-serving

I'm following [this](https://knative.dev/docs/getting-started/first-service/) guide to deploy a Knative Service and used [this](https://knative.dev/docs/install/yaml-install/serving/install-serving-with-yaml/) to install Knative Serving using YAML files.

When accessing the service using:

```
echo "Accessing URL $(kn service describe hello -o url)"
curl "$(kn service describe hello -o url)"
```

The expected output is `Hello World!` but I'm getting the Apache 2 Default Page HTML (same result when trying to access using browser). I've looked around and tried searching for similar issues but found nothing. I'm using minikube on WSL2 and Docker Desktop. Here's a list of resources in the `default` namespace:

```
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                         PORT(S)                                              AGE
service/hello                 ExternalName   <none>           kourier-internal.kourier-system.svc.cluster.local   80/TCP                                               26m
service/hello-00001           ClusterIP      10.104.200.89    <none>                                              80/TCP,443/TCP                                       26m
service/hello-00001-private   ClusterIP      10.111.171.183   <none>                                              80/TCP,443/TCP,9090/TCP,9091/TCP,8022/TCP,8012/TCP   26m
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>                                              443/TCP                                              26h

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hello-00001-deployment   0/0     0            0           26m

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hello-00001-deployment-cf98ddd5f   0         0         0       26m

NAME                                      LATESTCREATED   LATESTREADY   READY   REASON
configuration.serving.knative.dev/hello   hello-00001     hello-00001   True    

NAME                                       CONFIG NAME   K8S SERVICE NAME   GENERATION   READY   REASON   ACTUAL REPLICAS   DESIRED REPLICAS
revision.serving.knative.dev/hello-00001   hello                            1            True             0                 0

NAME                              URL                                       READY   REASON
route.serving.knative.dev/hello   http://hello.default.127.0.0.1.sslip.io   True    

NAME                                URL                                       LATESTCREATED   LATESTREADY   READY   REASON
service.serving.knative.dev/hello   http://hello.default.127.0.0.1.sslip.io   hello-00001     hello-00001   True
```

Here are the resources for `knative-serving`:

```
NAME                                          READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/activator-b7df55675-xgdxr                 1/1     Running     0          43m
pod/autoscaler-64655fb9c-fjdhv                1/1     Running     0          43m
pod/controller-7b854b6dfb-4rxl4               1/1     Running     0          43m
pod/default-domain-wpw76                      0/1     Completed   0          42m
pod/net-kourier-controller-5c9d54f679-s4jp2   1/1     Running     0          43m
pod/webhook-6977cb78d8-nwlf5                  1/1     Running     0          43m

NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                   AGE
service/activator-service            ClusterIP   10.102.215.26    <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP,80/TCP,81/TCP,443/TCP   43m
service/autoscaler                   ClusterIP   10.97.117.153    <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP,8080/TCP                43m
service/autoscaler-bucket-00-of-01   ClusterIP   10.108.208.24    <none>        8080/TCP                                  43m
service/controller                   ClusterIP   10.101.50.185    <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP                         43m
service/default-domain-service       ClusterIP   10.99.156.129    <none>        80/TCP                                    42m
service/net-kourier-controller       ClusterIP   10.100.189.234   <none>        18000/TCP                                 43m
service/webhook                      ClusterIP   10.109.189.12    <none>        9090/TCP,8008/TCP,443/TCP                 43m

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/activator                1/1     1            1           43m
deployment.apps/autoscaler               1/1     1            1           43m
deployment.apps/controller               1/1     1            1           43m
deployment.apps/net-kourier-controller   1/1     1            1           43m
deployment.apps/webhook                  1/1     1            1           43m

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/activator-b7df55675                 1         1         1       43m
replicaset.apps/autoscaler-64655fb9c                1         1         1       43m
replicaset.apps/controller-7b854b6dfb               1         1         1       43m
replicaset.apps/net-kourier-controller-5c9d54f679   1         1         1       43m
replicaset.apps/webhook-6977cb78d8                  1         1         1       43m

NAME                                            REFERENCE              TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/activator   Deployment/activator   0%/100%   1         20        1          43m
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/webhook     Deployment/webhook     2%/100%   1         5         1          43m

NAME                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/default-domain   1/1           93s        42m
```

And for `kourier-system`

```
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/3scale-kourier-gateway-58c8cb46c6-g25jc   1/1     Running   0          44m

NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kourier            LoadBalancer   10.103.170.143   127.0.0.1     80:30794/TCP,443:30848/TCP   44m
service/kourier-internal   ClusterIP      10.96.20.155     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP               44m

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/3scale-kourier-gateway   1/1     1            1           44m

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/3scale-kourier-gateway-58c8cb46c6   1         1         1       44m

NAME                                                         REFERENCE                           TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/3scale-kourier-gateway   Deployment/3scale-kourier-gateway   2%/100%   1         10        1          44m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Apache and nginx solved this issue for me. Followed the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235347/what-is-the-best-way-to-uninstall-nginx) to completely remove the services. Hope this helps anyone who encounter the same issue.